# Insert dynamic values in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to insert different values in a field in table based on the value of another field in the same table...

Below is the code mentioned...

```
if($resultInsert)

    {
       $result=mysql_query("SELECT MAX(propertys_uid) FROM `q43qy_jomres_propertys`",$conn);
        $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
        //echo $row[0];
        $custom=array('AreaID','ChainCode','Distance','GEO_ConfidenceLevel','HotelCityCode','HotelCode','NumFloors');
        for($i=0;$i<7;$i++)
        {
        //echo $custom[$i];
        $insert_custom="INSERT INTO `q43qy_jomres_custom_property_fields_data`(`fieldname`,`data`,`property_uid`)
                     VALUES('$custom[$i]','$rowTable[AreaID]','$row[0]')";
        echo $insert_custom;
        $resultInsertCustom = mysql_query($insert_custom);            
        //echo "Data Inserted.";
        }
```

The problem is that I want the value `$rowTable[AreaID]` to change with each `$custom[$i]` using a for loop... How can I do that?

Comment: how do you want it to change?

Comment: How it would change? What should be the value of `$rowTable[AreaID]`?

Comment: well $rowTable[AreaID] should become dynamic lyk..$rowTable[$i]...

Comment: wherein $rowTable[$i]...should contains the values from database which den passed under for loop to get all index of values of array $rowTable[].

Comment: $rowTable[$custom[$i]] ?